# get multiple items chosen in a listbox and populate new list with the values, using Tkinter

Tags: python, get, listbox, tkinter, selection

I am trying to take the selection from a listbox and populate a new list with it, and it will be multiple items. I can't figure this out, here's what i have so far (and I need the actual strings in the list, not the indices). Also, how can I completely get rid of the Tkinter widgets after making the selection - it closes out but it seems like there is a ghost of it still hanging around after it closes.

```
def execute(*events):
   UsrFCList = []
   selctd_indices = lbox.curselection()
   lst_select = list(selctd_indices)
   for i in lst_select:
      lbox.get(i)
      UsrFCList.append(i)
   lbox.quit()

fc_lb = Tk()
scrollbar = Scrollbar(fc_lb)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
lbox = AutoSzLB(fc_lb,selectmode=EXTENDED)
for item in lb_list:
  lbox.insert(END, *item)

button = Button(fc_lb, text="Analyze selected feature classes", command=execute)

lbox.autowidth(250)
lbox.pack()
button.pack()

lbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.config(command=lbox.yview)

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, instead of

```
for i in lst_select:
  lbox.get(i)
  UsrFCList.append(i)
```

It was

```
for i in lst_select:
    UsrFCList.append(lbox.get(i))
```