# How to read line by line for the "data" attribute ? Python

Tags: python, readlines

anyone know how do i read the "data" line by line?. My goal is to read the data line by line and send it to somewhere when pressing "send". Currently i'm able to read the data but it doesn't read as line by line.

[image: Here is my image]

**What i've done**

```
    def mouseHover(event):
        x = lbox.curselection()[0]
        file = lbox.get(x)
        self.s.send(("fdown~" + file).encode("utf-8")) 
        self.s.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")

        self.s.send("OK".encode("utf-8"))
        open(file , 'wb+')  #must have
        global data
        data = (self.s.recv(1024).decode("utf-8") ) 
        sys.stdout.flush()
        self.text.insert(tk.END, data)
    lbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", mouseHover)
```

Comment: did you try to split the data in file? using file.split() ? does it convert it to a list. Then you can iterate through the list line by line

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294503/get-multiple-items-chosen-in-a-listbox-and-populate-new-list-with-the-values-us

Comment: based on the examples I saw, i think you need to give `for i in x: lbox.get(i)` to get each line

Comment: Why are you calling `open()` without assigning the result to a variable? That will simply empty the file but never write anything to it.

Comment: `readlines()` is for reading lines from a file. If you have multiple lines in a string you can use `splitlines()`.

Comment: what do you mean in split data in file ya? Currently im able to read the file. But it cant be read it line by line. i want to do it because i need the data in the file to publish to my MQTT server. For example. textfileA = "1234",  I need the fileA value to be publish accordingly 1->2->3->4

Comment: @Barmar I have tried to assign a value to the openfile, but when i call it, it doesnt return any value. But if i call "data" the value will be show.

Comment: @Barmar So i was thinking, is it possible to read lines from the data instead of the openfile

Comment: @ZhuangAh Like I said, use `splitlines()` to convert the data into a list of lines. Then you can loop through the list.

Comment: What do you mean by "when I call it, it doesn't return any value". `wb+` mode means it's an output file that you write to, not an input file you read from.

Comment: `open(file, 'wb+')` means to use the value of `file` as the name of a file to create and write to.

Comment: @Barmar Ohh i got it. I successfully seperate the data into splitlines.                                   Result: [link](https://ibb.co/0YSypWh). So now i need to know how to loop it right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One could do something like this:

```
lines = [entry.strip() for entry in open("filename.txt", "r")]

for line in lines:
    [Do whatever]
```